# Create new column with rounded values

Tags: data-cleaning

I am trying to create a new column in this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/chocolate-bar-ratings/). I would like to have rating to be 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 instead of 1.25, 2.00, 3.75, ..., 5.00. 
Can you help me? The only solution I found is this

```
chocolate$Rat = gsub("1.25", "1", chocolate$Rating)
```

but I know it is not a good way to work. Is there something faster which can to the work efficiently?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want 3.75 as 3 or 4…?

Comment: If possible, 4. but If you can only round to 3 it's not a problem

Comment: I want to use it to learn about associative rules and test how it works. I have an example with "titanic" dataset and I think this dataset could also work. My idea is to see the combinations which lead to "rating =1, rating =2, rating=3, rating=4, rating=5" with the apriori() algorithm

Comment: Just google round in r.

Comment: Also, I am thinking about using this new column to build a decisional tree. Do you think it could work?

Comment: I copied the "old" column into a new one and then rounded it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R function is “round”. The default is to round to the nearest integer, which is what you want. The function takes vector inputs, so you can apply it to your column in one line instead of using a “for” loop.

Then you’ll tack in on to your original data in any number of ways, such as “expanded_data <- data.frame(original_data, round(column))”.

Comment: Thank you very much!